# Actionscript 3, read file text at compile time?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, embed

There is some way to make the flash put the content of one text file in a string, or at least put it in the .swf, so the user don't need to download it?

Comment: What environment are you working under? FlexBuilder? CS3? Command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
[Embed(source = "ExampleText.txt", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
protected var pscene:Class;

var tmp:ByteArray = new pscene();
result = tmp.readMultiByte(tmp.bytesAvailable, tmp.endian);
```

It took me a while to understand how to read the data from the Byte Array.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used a pre-compile step to populate a template. It's pretty easy to make a class that has a string to be populated before compilation.

Ant can do this pretty easily. Check out the [`replace` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html).

Comment: What does apache can teach me about actionscript 3? o_O
I mean, flash is compiled, I don't think the text can be replaced by the apache.

Comment: The apache project umbrella contains a whole host of subprojects. One of which is a build system called ant.